# Firefox Browser Console reports several errors on Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install

Tags: 20.04, firefox

In both my live USB (official 20.04 iso) and a fresh Focal install, Firefox reports a few different errors in the Browser Console every time it is launched. This happens with new FF profile, no add-ons, cookies etc. I've reset profiles anyways and it still persists. Booting firefox in safe mode does not do anything. I've updated/upgraded with apt & snap, the issue still persists. I tried FF on the live USB on two different computers and the same errors appeared. I've re-downloaded the iso and re-made the live USB, still no change. I think these may be unresolved low priority bugs but I cannot find ANYTHING online regarding them, which I find surprising if they were common bugs.

These errors are not causing any issues per se (although I do see error messages frequently when browsing and especially so with any add-ons). However, I've spun my wheels long enough that I need some sort of closure haha. Are these just bugs? Does anyone else get these same errors? Is there some underlying issue that I could fix besides my anal personality?

```
22:37:33.870 [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsICommandLine.handleFlagWithParam]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/BrowserContentHandler.jsm :: bch_handle :: line 415"  data: no] BrowserContentHandler.jsm:415:34

2:37:33.871 Warning: unrecognized command line flag -new-window
BrowserContentHandler.jsm:989

22:37:34.376 browser.startup.average_time - Truncating float/double number.

22:37:34.380 [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIAppStartup.secondsSinceLastOSRestart]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/BrowserGlue.jsm :: _collectStartupConditionsTelemetry :: line 1682"  data: no] BrowserGlue.jsm:1682:9

22:37:34.673 Unknown category for SetEventRecordingEnabled: fxmonitor

22:37:35.567 Cc[aContract] is undefined XPCOMUtils.jsm:144

22:37:40.306 debuggee 'resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js:289' would run builtin-modules.js:196:11
```